# Error -27257 in Load runner

Tags: loadrunner

I am getting the following error while replaying the load runner script. I used auto correlation after recording the script and it has web_reg_save_param_regexp, which is causing the issue.

Error -27257: Pending web_reg_save_param/web_create_html_param/web_create_html_param_ex/web_reg_find request(s) detected and reset at the end of iteration number 1

Answer (score 0):

When auto correlation fails, use manual correlation.

Best guess is that you have an application which is returning HTTP 200 class pages and you have not implemented checking for expected results and branching when those expected results fail.  As a result your last correlation/check cannot be satisfied, which is why it is still pending at the end of the iteration.

Testing 101:  For every step there is a positive, expected output.  Check for that output and terminate your virtual user when that output is not achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Do the manual correlation instead of auto correlation. Manual correlation is a good practice.

Suppose your response is: "paramName:**123456**&key=...", and you want to extract the bold part. Then add this line above your request:

```
web_reg_save_param("c_paramname", "LB=paramName:", "RB=&key=", LAST);
```